# .htaccess redirects same view for two different urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've an old url of my website `http://babycareadvice.com/article/detail/59` which i want to redirect to new url like this `http://babycareadvice.com)/article/detail/What_Causes_Baby_Diarrhea`. 
I've written a .htaccess redirect rule :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /article/detail/59 [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/?(http://babycareadvice.com)? /article/detail/What_Causes_Baby_Diarrhea? [R=301]
```

This works perfectly but an other old url of my website :

```
http://babycareadvice.com/article/detail/Baby_Safe_Sleeping_Recommendations/article/detail/59
```

also redirects as previous rule but i want this url to redirect to :

```
http://babycareadvice.com/article/detail/Baby_Safe_Sleeping_Recommendations
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule to ensure you don't match any unwanted URL on either side:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+article/detail/59[/?\s] [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /article/detail/What_Causes_Baby_Diarrhea? [R=301,L]  

# rest of your rule go here
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing.